# How to do a scatter plot with empty circles in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, scatter-plot, scatter

In Python, with Matplotlib, how can a scatter plot with *empty* circles be plotted?  The goal is to draw empty circles around *some* of the colored disks already plotted by `scatter()`, so as to highlight them, ideally without having to redraw the colored circles.

I tried `facecolors=None`, to no avail.

Comment: People looking to draw empty/hollow scatter plots with different colors may look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250916/matplotlib-scatter-edge-without-specifying-edgecolor).

Answer (score 383, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) for scatter:

```
Optional kwargs control the Collection properties; in particular:

    edgecolors:
        The string ‘none’ to plot faces with no outlines
    facecolors:
        The string ‘none’ to plot unfilled outlines
```

Try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.random.randn(60) 
y = np.random.randn(60)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
plt.show()
```

[image: example image]

**Note:** For other types of plots see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956903/how-to-make-hollow-square-marks-with-matplotlib-in-python) on the use of `markeredgecolor` and `markerfacecolor`.

Comment: Thanks! The gotcha is that the more usual (in Python) `facecolors=None` does not work, which tripped me.

Comment: Very helpful. It's `markerfacecolor='none'`, this is the way it's now.

Comment: I had my matplotlib style in a way that set the edges widths to zero. If you don't see any markers with `markerfacecolor='none'` try adding `markeredgewidth=1.0`

Comment: This approach can also be used in Seaborn after doing the standard import of Matplotlib `%matplotlib inline` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, and then setting Seaborn to be the plotting default by `import seaborn as sns; sns.set()`

Comment: The edge widths are currently (v3.4.2) specified by the parameter `linewidths` instead of `markeredgewidth`. [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)

Comment: Can be abbreviated, e.g. `fc='none', ec='r'`

Answer (score 102):

Would these work?

```
plt.scatter(np.random.randn(100), np.random.randn(100), facecolors='none')
```

[image: example image]

or using plot()

```
plt.plot(np.random.randn(100), np.random.randn(100), 'o', mfc='none')
```

[image: example image]

Comment: this is useful for when you use `plot` instead of `scatter`

Comment: For `scatter`, you need to specify `edgecolors` like  `edgecolors='r'`. Otherwise, the circles disappear. [See here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

Comment: @T_T If I specify `edgecolors='r'` I have to specify a color by hand. Is there a way to have the empty circles not disappear, but letting PyPlot choose automatic the colors for each series?

Comment: @becko No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another way: this adds a circle to the current axes, plot or image or whatever :

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle  # $matplotlib/patches.py

def circle( xy, radius, color="lightsteelblue", facecolor="none", alpha=1, ax=None ):
    """ add a circle to ax= or current axes
    """
        # from .../pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.py
    e = Circle( xy=xy, radius=radius )
    if ax is None:
        ax = pl.gca()  # ax = subplot( 1,1,1 )
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
    e.set_edgecolor( color )
    e.set_facecolor( facecolor )  # "none" not None
    e.set_alpha( alpha )
```

[image]

(The circles in the picture get squashed to ellipses because `imshow aspect="auto"` ).

Answer (score 7):

Basend on the example of Gary Kerr and as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620370/add-colorbar-to-scatterplot-with-non-filled-circles) one may create empty circles related to specified values with following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle

x = np.random.randn(60) 
y = np.random.randn(60)
z = np.random.randn(60)

g=plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z)
g.set_facecolor('none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the essentially a complexified version the accepted answer…

Comment: From my point is it not. Using scatter plot with colors does not except facecolor="none" within the command. Therefor the subsequent removement of the facecolor is needed as described in the given link. Unfortunaly this complexified solution is needed to remove the facecolor in scatter plots with colorcoding.

Comment: The approach in this answer is indeed useful if one wants to update a graph that originally does not contain empty circles. However, the question about _creating_ these circles directly, so the accepted solution is the way to go, as it does the same as this answer but directly, with no extraneous update of a first graph.

Comment: This "complexified version" worked for me when embedding the argument within `.scatter()` did not.  For context, I was also applying a colormap (`c=z, cmap='jet'`).

Comment: this was the only answer that actually worked for empty circles with different colors

Answer (score 6):

In matplotlib 2.0 there is a parameter called `fillstyle`
which allows better control on the way markers are filled. 
In my case I have used it with errorbars but it works for markers in general
http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html

`fillstyle` accepts the following values: [‘full’ | ‘left’ | ‘right’ | ‘bottom’ | ‘top’ | ‘none’]

There are two important things to keep in mind when using `fillstyle`,

1) If mfc is set to any kind of value it will take priority, hence, if you did set fillstyle to 'none' it would not take effect.
So avoid using mfc in conjuntion with fillstyle

2) You might want to control the marker edge width (using `markeredgewidth` or `mew`) because if the marker is relatively small and the edge width is thick, the markers will look like filled even though they are not.

Following is an example using errorbars:

```
myplot.errorbar(x=myXval, y=myYval, yerr=myYerrVal, fmt='o', fillstyle='none', ecolor='blue',  mec='blue')
```

Comment: Good tip re controlling of the line widths! The `markeredgewidth` parameter is called `linewidths` in **matplotlib 3.3.1**. See up-to-date information in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you want to highlight some points that fit a certain criteria. You can use Prelude's command to do a second scatter plot of the hightlighted points with an empty circle and a first call to plot all the points. Make sure the s paramter is sufficiently small for the larger empty circles to enclose the smaller filled ones.

The other option is to not use scatter and draw the patches individually using the circle/ellipse command. These are in matplotlib.patches, [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/patch_collection.html) is some sample code on how to draw circles rectangles etc.