# how to make hollow square marks with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Black line in the following graph is plotting using the below command for matplotlib python

```
pylab.semilogy(xaxis, pq_averages, 'ks-',color='black', label='DCTCP-PQ47.5')
```

So 'ks-' part indicates solid line with square black marks. So it had solid squares for the plotted points. Can these squares be made hollow instead?

[image]

Comment: microseconds is typically one word :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try adding `markerfacecolor` like so:

```
pylab.semilogy(xaxis, pq_averages, 'ks-', markerfacecolor='none', label='DCTCP-PQ47.5')
```

Comment: Nice answer. Slightly improved would be to use `markerfacecolor='none'`, but in general, your solution will be perfect 90% of the time.

Comment: @pelson: yes, that is better - I was not aware that 'none' was accepted as a color.

Comment: @HughBothwell, can you edit the answer to use markerfacecolor='none'?

Comment: In matplotlib 3.0.2, there is apparently no markerfacecolor.  facecolor='none' does work.

Comment: For those who run out of space writing parameters for pyplot: `markerfacecolor` can be abbreviated `mfc`, there are also `mec` and even `mew`. See [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot).

Comment: For those that get `markerfacecolor` is an unexpected argument while trying a scatter plot, you should instead use `facecolors='none'`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474817/5809639)

Answer (score 13):

Setting `markerfacecolor='white'` does not actually make them hollow, it makes them white. In order to make them hollow, you need to set `markerfacecolor='none'`.
Additionally, you need to set `markeredgecolor` to the color you want.
So:

```
pylab.semilogy(xaxis, pq_averages, 'ks-',color='black',
       label='DCTCP-PQ47.5', markerfacecolor='none', markeredgecolor='black')
```

Will do the job for you.

Comment: "Additionally, you need to set `markerfacecolor` to the color you want." You mean `markeredgecolor` here, right?