# Matplotlib scatter plot of unfilled squares

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a scatter plot with unfilled squares. `markerfacecolor` is not an option recognized by [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). I made a `MarkerStyle` but the fill style seems to be ignored by the scatter plot. Is there a way to make unfilled markers in the scatterplot?

```
import matplotlib.markers as markers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

def main():
    size = [595, 842] # in pixels
    dpi = 72. # dots per inch
    figsize = [i / dpi for i in size]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

    x_max = 52
    y_max = 90
    ax.set_xlim([0, x_max+1])
    ax.set_ylim([0, y_max + 1]) 

    x = np.arange(1, x_max+1)
    y = [np.arange(1, y_max+1) for i in range(x_max)]

    marker = markers.MarkerStyle(marker='s', fillstyle='none')
    for temp in zip(*y):
        plt.scatter(x, temp, color='green', marker=marker)

    plt.show()

main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear that if you want to use `plt.scatter()` then you have to use `facecolors = 'none'` instead of setting `fillstyle = 'none'` in construction of the `MarkerStyle`, e.g.

```py
marker = markers.MarkerStyle(marker='s')
for temp in zip(*y):
    plt.scatter(x, temp, color='green', marker=marker, facecolors='none')

plt.show()
```

or, use `plt.plot()` with `fillstyle = 'none'` and `linestyle = 'none'` but since the `marker` keyword in `plt.plot` does not support `MarkerStyle` objects you have to specify the style inline, i.e.

```py
for temp in zip(*y):
    plt.plot(x, temp, color='green', marker='s', fillstyle='none')

plt.show()
```

either of which will give you something that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Note that when using `scatter`, the keyword `c` and `color` don't behave the same way. Setting `c='green'` plots filled squares, while `color='green'` or `edgecolors='green'` does not fill the squares.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to: [How to do a scatter plot with empty circles in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143502/how-to-do-a-scatter-plot-with-empty-circles-in-python)

Try adding `facecolors='none'` to your `plt.scatter`

```
plt.scatter(x, temp, color='green', marker=marker, facecolors='none')
```

Comment: Ah, yes. The link off of the scatter documentation. I missed it. Thank you.

Comment: My mistake sorry, I was going off an older version of the page that still listed the facecolors kwarg in the documentation, seems like they some edits.