# Plot empty markers in y vs x plot with colors according to z values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot empty circles in y vs x plot and I found a very nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146439/7298014)
I wanted to ask if I can set the edge colour according to the values of a third array.
I modified the code as following, but as expected, I can only pass color values to edge color:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.random.randn(60) 
y = np.random.randn(60)
z = np.random.randn(60)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors=z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ideas:

```
# define some condition for colors:
colors = ['red' if a < 0 else 'blue' for a in z ]
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors=colors)


# get colors directly from colormap
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors=plt.cm.viridis(z))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I prefer the second one.